# Can't install mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm at my wit's end trying to install mysql2.

I'm running on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.  I installed `ruby 1.9.3`; `rails 3.2.9`.  Everything goes fine - until I try to install mysql2 - either by including it in the Gemfile and running bundle install, or trying to install it by running `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'`

The error I get is 
`'Could not create Make file due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.'`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you installed the mysql server? `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have `libmysqlclient-dev` installed.

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Try installing mysql gem after installing this package

Answer (score 1):

To get MySQL support for Rails:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Add the MySQL gem to your gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Followed by 'bundle', to let bundler install the gem.

And don't forget to change your config/database.yml, as in:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: [database]
  pool: [n]
  username: [username]
  password: [password]
  host: [host]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Just add `libmysqlclient-dev` package using apt-get.

2) Then run the `gem install mysql2` command.